# Creating Schema for Users with Friends without many to many relationship?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, django, django-models

I'm working on my first Django app and trying to create the models for it but am stuck on how to create what I think should be a simple model relationship.  I want to create a model for a user, with typical attributes like username, password(hash of course), date joined, etc. Then would like to be able to link this user to all of their friends/followers on the site. But where i'm stuck is how i setup that relationship since one user can have many friends, I can key off that primary key for the User table, but how do i create a model for the friends table that has the primary key for the user table serve two functions, one as the mapping to the user, and the mapping to the primary key for all of their friends?

```
 from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dateJoined = models.DateField('date joined')

class Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Why "without many to many relationship"? That's exactly what this is, a many to many relationship. One table with two columns, both of which are foreign keys to User.ID.

Comment: Somewhat related ... you should really look into using the Django Auth module. It would save you from writing a lot of your own user management stuff. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: @RJ thats helpful but still doesnt help me with the relationship between the users and friends.

Comment: An ORM isn't a substitute for understanding relational databases.  You shouldn't try to use Django before learning SQL, or you'll end up trying to implement a many-to-many relationship without using a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend you not create your own User model, instead use the one that comes built in Django. It takes care of all the fields that you're looking for.

Second, I would also create a "profile" model and store my friends in that. Have a look here on what profiles are: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Third, in your profile model, I would add a field for friends exactly as it's shown here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

You can then access friends for a user like `user.get_profile().friends.all()`. A bit verbose, but keeps things clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE friends (user_id int, friend_id int)
```

Both columns reference the user ID. I don't know Django models, but guessing from your code, it'd look like:

```
class Friends(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: The models validate before appending your suggested line. After I do that I receive the following error. Error: One or more models did not validate:
gamer.friends: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.f
riends_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
gamer.friends: Accessor for field 'friend' clashes with related field 'User.friends_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'friend'.

Comment: You need to add a related_name. Something like `user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friends')` and `friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='following')`. You can then access the related manager like `user.friends.filter(dateJoined__gte=...)` and what not.